# Add UITapGestureRecognizer to UITextView without blocking textView touches

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uitapgesturerecognizer

How can I add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to a UITextView but still have the touches getting through to the `UITextView` as *normal*?

Currently as soon as I add a custom gesture to my textView it blocks the tap for UITextView default actions like positioning the cursor.

```
var tapTerm:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    tapTerm = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapTextView:")
    textView.addGestureRecognizer(tapTerm)
}

func tapTextView(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    println("tapped term – but blocking the tap for textView :-/")
…
}
```

How can I process taps but keep any textView behaviour like cursor positioning as is?

Comment: Have you tried setting `cancelsTouchesInView` to `false`?

Comment: What will you do when you want to move the cursor?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To do that make your view controller adopt to UIGestureRecognizerDelegate and override should recognize simultaneously with gesture recognizer method like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    tapTerm = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapTextView:")
    tapTerm.delegate = self
    textView.addGestureRecognizer(tapTerm)
}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: I've implemented this to negate another issue that I'm facing, but to no avail. Please find that at, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517995/imessage-extension-crashes-while-trying-to-access-in-compact-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517995/imessage-extension-crashes-while-trying-to-access-in-compact-mode)

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  It merely toggles the gesture recognizer without SHARING events between the UITextView & Tap-Gesture Recognizer.   

I want to be able to scroll the text AND to be able to tap or double-tap to exit the UITextView/UIViewController via UIGestureRecognizer.

It's not elegant to having to share the screen real-estate with a UIButton to exit.

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone came here looking for @Zell B.'s answer in Objective C, here's the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(textViewTapped:)];
    tap.delegate = self; 
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1; 
   [self.textView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}   

- (void)textViewTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {
    //DO SOMTHING 
}

#pragma mark - Gesture recognizer delegate

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES; 
}
```

PS: Don't forget < UIGestureRecognizerDelegate >

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2** 
The following steps allows me to escape a full-screen UITextView with a tap, whilst allowing to scroll the contents of the UITextView:

1. Disconnected the UIGestureRecognizer from the UITableView.
2. Made a CustomTextView: UITextView.
3. Added a 'sender' var to the particular UIViewController with the CustomTextView.
4. Trap for 'Touches Ended...'
5. Call for an excape function within the sender UIViewController.

```
class CustomTextView: UITextView {
    var sender: DocViewController?

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let controller = sender {
            controller.handleSwipeGesture()
        }
    }
}
```

I can either scroll the contents of the UITextView or merely tap to exit.

The 'sender' is set from the hosting UIViewController at creation.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I could not assign a delegate inside UIView so I came up with a button solution.

I insert a button that completely covers the textView and when tapped on textViewButton I do resign the button so textView shows.

```
 @IBAction func textViewTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.placeholderLabel.isHidden = true
        self.textViewButton.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```