# UIPinchGestureRecognizer does not get past Possible state

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I have

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.multipleTouchEnabled = true
        let pinchRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePinch:")

        pinchRecognizer.delegate = self
        self.addGestureRecognizer(pinchRecognizer)
    }

 @objc func handlePinch(recognizer:UIPinchGestureRecognizer){
        print("pinch")
        switch recognizer.state {
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
            //Code
            break
        default:
            break
        }
```

But handlePinch() never gets called, so I added

```
override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    print(gestureRecognizer)
    return true
}
```

This prints

```
<UIPinchGestureRecognizer: 0x135d0f4e0; state = Possible; view = <Equalizer.GraphContainer 0x135e0a470>; target= <(action=handlePinch:, target=<Equalizer.GraphContainer 0x135e0a470>)>>
```

Apparently UIPinchGestureRecognizer never gets past the "Possible" state.
Once in a blue moon it actually does get through and my handlePinch() does get called.

What am I missing here?

Comment: How do you initialize your view and are you sure init with coder is called ?

Comment: Yes, I actually have pan and tap gestures already working on the same view.  the init method is shown. it's loaded from the storyboard...

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28859225/1422333 . I think the problem is with pinch and pan conflicting each other

Comment: I will try that when I get to home.  But I have already commented out the other gestures completely, since I suspected the same thing.

Comment: Ok, that's exactly what the problem was! Thanks