# can not call selector and gesture delegate iOS 13.2

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, ios13, uipangesturerecognizer, xcode11

my code works in iOS 12 last version but after iOS 13 this code can't call the selector 
I used **UIGestureRecognizerDelegate** for iOS 13

here is my code

```
let panGest = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
panGest.delegate = self
txtVw.addGestureRecognizer(panGest)
```

here is my let txtVw = subVws as! UITextView ,  `txtVw = subVws as! UITextView`

I used this code:

```
let panGest = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTap(_:)))
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGest)
```

its work but I have one subview and for subview isn't work & call !!

isn't call self.handleTap or `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:)`

Comment: Why on earth you force cast some view to `UITextView` ? also this is the worst naming one possibly could use. Anyway, try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53146108/689779

Comment: @Maysam because I need this UItextview for pdfkit and it was work in iOS 12

Comment: @Maysam can you write the code with pan gesture with my code ? in your link you isn't change !!!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

[image]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
        gestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        textView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
        textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        textView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
    }

    @objc func handlePan(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if gestureRecognizer.state == .began || gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {

            let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)
            //make sure the view is not nil
            gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)
            gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: are you work with PDFKit ? if yes can you open one chat ?

Comment: No i have not ever used PDFKit